# Degree of a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

How to calculate the degree of the splitting field $X^3+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know that I need to first find the minimal polynomial which will give me what the splitting field is equal to but I don't know how to factorise it.

Comment: You could use the rational root theorem to show that $X^3+2$ has no roots in $\Bbb Q$

Comment: "Minimal polynomial" is something you attach to algebraic numbers, not to polynomials.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner if it has no roots then is the degree just the highest degree of $X$?

Comment: if a cubic polynomial has no roots, then it's irreducible

Comment: @J.W.Tanner if it's irreducible then the solutions are the 3 roots of unity right?  Then do I find the lcm of the degree of the polynomial and the degree of the 3 roots of unity?

Comment: A cubic root of unity is a complex number $\zeta$ satisfying $\zeta^3=1$. Is such a complex number a root of $x^3+2$?

Comment: my question is +2 so intuitively I would say no... @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Typo; but still, can't be a root. So the solutions are *not* "the cubic roots of unity", as you asked.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm so confused I have no idea what other options there are... unless it  is not a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#Cubic_example) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737425/the-splitting-field-of-x3-2-over-mathbbq-and-its-degree)

Comment: What "it"? You are confusing different categories of things. First you talk about "minimal polynomials" when you don't have any algebraic elements to discuss (as I said, "minimal polynomial" is something related to a given algebraic element, not to a polynomial). Now you talk about "it's not a splitting field", when you don't have any extensions to discuss! You can ask whether a given *extension* is a splitting field, but not whether a *polynomial* is a "splitting field". A polynomial is not even a field! Do you understand what you are being asked to find?

Comment: Either the polynomial splits after adjoining one of its roots, then the degree is equal to the degree of the polynomial, $3$. Or it splits after adjoining two roots, in which case the degree is $6$ (think about why this is so). Now find out wether it splits after adjoining one or two roots.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am simply trying to gain more understanding of a question. No need to get angry

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos thanks!

Comment: I’m not getting angry. I am asking if (i) you understand what the words you are using mean; and (ii) you understand what you are being asked to do. No sense in spending time trying to answer your questions unless the answer is affirmative in both cases, and you are woefully misusing the terms, suggesting that in fact the answer in both instances is negative. Which would mean that you need to take several steps back and fix the issues that underlie those misunderstanding, instead of trying to solve a problem you do not understand head on.

Comment: I thought stack exchange is a place where others can help with your misunderstandings! I have not asked anyone to just give me the answer either. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: And I’m trying to help you figure out *where* your misunderstandings lie. You are asking for help with a problem, but your comments surrounding the problem suggests that you really need help with the underlying concepts, not with the mechanics of solving this problem. So you should be asking about those, rather than about this problem. And nowhere did *I* suggest you were “just” asking for the answer; I merely pointed out that you seem to have some underlying misunderstandings that you need to fix before proceeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(r_1,r_2,r_3)$, where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the three roots of the polynomial $X^3+2$.

This is just the definition, but it's the starting point anyway. How do we know that the polynomial has distinct roots? The derivative test, of course: the derivative is $3X^2$ which has no nonconstant common factor with $X^3+2$.

Now let's look at the polynomial again: it has no rational roots, because $\pm1$ and $\pm2$ aren't roots. Since it has degree three, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but this is not that important in order to find the splitting field.

Suppose we are in an extension where all roots exist. Thus we can factor $X^3+2=(X-r_1)(X-r_2)(X-r_3)$; however, $r_1^3=-2$, so we also get the factorization
$$
(X-r_1)(X^2+r_1X+r_1^2)
$$
What does this entail? That $(X-r_2)(X-r_3)=X^2+r_1X+r_1^2$ and therefore
$$
r_2+r_3=-r_1,\quad r_2r_3=r_1^2
$$
This is the same as saying that $a+b=-1$, $ab=1$, where $a=r_2/r_1$, $b=r_3/r_1$. In particular $a$ and $b$ are roots of $X^2+X+1$, so they're the nonreal cube roots of $1$. If we call $\omega$ one of them, the other one is $\omega^2$.

Hence $r_2=\omega r_1$ and $r_3=\omega^2 r_1$. Now we can make a choice: take $r_1=r=-\sqrt[3]{2}$ (the *real* cube root). Then the splitting field is
$$
\mathbb{Q}(r,\omega r,\omega^2r)=\mathbb{Q}(r,\omega)
$$
You know that $[\mathbb{Q}(r):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

Can you compute $[\mathbb{Q}(r,\omega):\mathbb{Q}(r)]$?

---

You're starting with the wrong foot. The given polynomial is irreducible, so it *is* the minimal polynomial of any of its roots.

You also seem to believe that if $f(X)$ is the minimal polynomial for some algebraic number, then $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$ is the splitting field for $f(X)$. This is not true, in general, and the example shows it: the minimal polynomial for $r=-\sqrt[3]{2}$ is $X^3+2$, but $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3+2)\cong\mathbb{Q}(r)$ is *not* the splitting field because it doesn't contain $\omega$.

Comment: I just remember that these are field extensions and I don't know their use :-(  But what is the sense of $[\mathbb{B} :\mathbb{G}]=\cdots$, for example? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano If $K$ is an extension field of $F$, then $[K:F]$ denotes the dimension of $K$ as an $F$-vector space.