# Order of galois group of splitting field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Something silly question, but I can’t figure out what is wrong.

For example, suppose $K$ be a splitting field of $x^4 - 4x^2 -1$ over $Q$.

Of course, it is irreducible, and zeros are $\pm \sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}$ and $\pm i \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$. So $K$ would be $Q( \sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}, i \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2})$. So the order of galois group would be 8.

However, K is a finite normal extension of Q, which is seperable splitting field over $Q$. Then the order of galois group must be equal to the number of roots of $x^4 - 4x^2 -1$. Then it must be 4…

What did I misunderstood?

Comment: My mistake. Edited it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Degree of a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922784/degree-of-a-splitting-field-over-mathbbq) Look at the end of the accepted answer.  Why should the order of Galois group be equal to the number of roots?

Comment: It's not true that the Galois group of a separable polynomial has the same order as the amount of roots of the polynomial in general (if the polynomial is irreducible, then the order is divisible by the amount of roots).

Comment: @AnneBauval No. Actually I got the order of galois group 8 by the similar way. So I know the order is 8. But what I am curious is why it is not 4, even though $|G(K/Q)| = [K : Q]  = 4$.

Comment: Actually, it does: the end of [the accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3922932/386889), on which I drew your attention, explains that $[K:\Bbb Q]\ne4.$ The splitting field is not $\Bbb Q[X]/(f).$

Comment: @AntonOdina But doesn’t $[K : Q]$ mean the order of polynomial in this case? Isn’t it?

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, now I got something. Then $[K : Q] = [K : Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}})] [Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}) : Q] = 2 \times 4 = 8$. Right?

Comment: Nothing new (this was the fine "similar way" you were mentionning previously). Your misunderstanding was about your other (wrong) way, leading to $4,$ and the confusion was explained above.