# Are all rings of integers closed under conjugation?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As far as I know rings of integers are "made up" of integers and some complex numbers (and their sums and multiplications and so on). My question is, are they always closed under complex conjugation? The "typical" examples such as Gaussian, cyclotomic or quadratic integer rings are, but I'm not sure if this is just because they are on the nicer part when it comes to rings of integers, or because every one has this property, and I can't find a counter-example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fields you mention are all Galois extensions of the rational numbers, so they contain all of their (complex) conjugates. A counterexample would be $K=\Bbb Q(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. $K$ and hence also the ring of integers ${\cal O}_K$ in $K$ is not closed under complex conjugation since $\overline{\omega\sqrt[3]{2}}=\overline{\omega}\sqrt[3]{2}=\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}\notin K$ (otherwise $K$ would be the splitting field of $x^3-2$, which is not the case, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737425/the-splitting-field-of-x3-2-over-mathbbq-and-its-degree)).